# Commit to 2 different Github repositories in Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio, github

Is it possible to commit to two different Github repos from Android Studio? At the moment I've been able to push commits to a Github project, but I've not been able to connect another Github repo to Android Studio.

If possible, would I then be able to specify the repo I'm committing to?

Comment: I recently saw a question here about this, and I'm not sure if there was an IDE based resolution.  But, you can always handle this from the command line as a backup option.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I guess I'll stick to Git Bash then.